# How do I deserialize a map field in Unity from Firestore?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-firestore

I am successfully retrieving my Firestore document, which looks something like this:
[image]

I created `myMap` by updating the document with an instance of this class:

```
using System;
using Firebase.Firestore;

[FirestoreData]
public class MyData
{
    [FirestoreProperty("myBoolean")]
    public bool MyBoolean { get; set; }

    [FirestoreProperty("myNumber")]
    public int MyNumber { get; set; }

    [FirestoreProperty("myTimestamp")]
    public DateTime MyTimestamp { get; set; }
}
```

How do I convert `myMap` back into an instance of `MyMap` after retrieving the document?

I can use `myDocumentSnapshot.ConvertTo<MyMap>();` to convert an entire document, but I do not know how to do it for a map within a document.

I am trying to do something along these lines, except `ConvertTo` does not work in this context:

```
var myDocument = myDocumentSnapshot.ToDictionary();
var myMap = myDocument["myMap"].ConvertTo<MyMap>();
```

How can I deserialize `MyMap` after retrieving the document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No expert at all but following the docs I think you would use [`GetValue`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/firestore/document-snapshot#getvalue-t_1) like e.g.

```
var myMap = myDocument.GetValue<MyMap>("myMap");
```

or in order to not get an exception [`TryGetValue`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/firestore/document-snapshot#trygetvalue-t) like e.g.

```
if(!myDocument.TryGetValue<MyMap>("myMap", out var myMap)
{
    Debug.LogError("Could not deserialize myMap!");
}
```